# How to solve "p:message not working" in Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm building a form that let the user enter database connection parameters. Once the parameters are typed
the user can test (btnTester) if connection can be established with its parameters.

In all cases, a message is produced for the user. Here the example of a failed connection attempt from backing bean code :

```
(...)
addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Connection failed.", t.getLocalizedMessage()));
(...)
```

Here is the form code. I'd like the message to appear in a p:message. Unfortunately, nothing happen. No message (connection successful or not) is displayed after the button :\
Even with the global attribute set to false or true.

```
<h:form prependId="false">
(...)
  <h:panelGrid>                 
    <!-- Other form components here -->
    <f:facet name="footer">
      <p:commandButton
          id="btnTester"
          value="Tester"
          actionListener="#{assistantCreationSourcesBean.testerConnexionBase}"
          update="msgTester" />
          <p:message id="msgTester" for="btnTester" />
    </f:facet>
 </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a growl instead of a message for solving my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an `update` attribute on your `<p:commandButton>` that specifies the ID of the `<p:message>` component to update.

You should give the message component and ID and specify it in `update` of the commandButton.

Comment: I've try it, Primefaces still doesn't want to show me any message. WTF??

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right ID in `update`?  The id of your form will probably prepend itself to the id of your message component.  Try adding `prependId="false"` to your `<h:form>` tag.

Comment: I have edited my initial post for reflecting what I have tested so far... Primefaces still doesn't show anything.

Comment: You have a typo, you wrote `preprendId="false"` instead of `prependId="false"`

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is here:

```
addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Connection failed.", t.getLocalizedMessage()));
```

I'm assuming that you're calling `FacesContext.addMessage()`. That first parameter is the component id string. If you set it to null, then you force the message to be a global message. The `<p:message>` component you have defined is set to `for="btnTester"` so it will only display messages with a component id that matches the id of your btnTester component.

Except from the Javadoc for `addMessage()`:

> Append a FacesMessage to the set of messages associated with the specified client identifier, if clientId is not null. If clientId is null, this FacesMessage is assumed to not be associated with any specific component instance.

[Link to FacesMessage Javadoc for addMessage() method](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29)

Answer (score 1):

**Found a solution that works Perfectly with message in Prime face.**

Thought Sharing with you even if u worked it out with growl

**Here is the solution**

The add addMessage has 2 parameters, a UIComponent Client Id and FacesMessage. The facesMessage shows or defines the message and Component Child Id shows where the component is. 
Here you have missed the Component Part.
In-order to make it work you should bind the UIComponent with the bean class.
So that it can find the Component .

Now do as follows,

> Define a UIComponent in bean class
>
> Bind it with the corresponding command Button
>
> and get the Id From the component in the bean Class

Your Code must be changed like this

```
>  private UIComponent component;

(...)
addMessage(component.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
"Connection failed.", t.getLocalizedMessage()));
(...)
```

Inside the xhtml file you must bind the UIComponent

```
<h:form prependId="false">
(...)
  <h:panelGrid>                 
    <!-- Other form components here -->
    <f:facet name="footer">
      <p:commandButton
          id="btnTester"
          value="Tester"
          actionListener="#{assistantCreationSourcesBean.testerConnexionBase}"
          update="msgTester" 
          binding="#{assistantCreationSourcesBean.component}"/>
          <p:message id="msgTester" for="btnTester" />
    </f:facet>
 </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Now the message will work..!! For me it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Here "for" attribute won't work for p:message use p:messages instead.

`<p:messages id="txtname" showIcon="false" 
    showDetail="true" showSummary="false" 
    redisplay="false" for="someKey" display="text"/>`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you try to update a component that not yet being render. Try this

Use Firefox Firebug and check the html source to see if component id `msgTester` exist. If it is not then it explain why your update wont work. You cant update something that it is not there. How to fix this, well you can create a wrapper for this, and update your wrapper. Your wrapper should be something that it is always there, like `h:form`. IF you dont want to update the whole form, then you can try `<p:outputPanel id="wrapper">`. so your code would look like this

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:outputPanel id="wrapper">
        <p:commandButton ... update="wrapper"/>
        <p:message />
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

try this and let me know if it work.

Comment: I've tried your solution, with no more chance. PF still doesn't show the message :(

Comment: Did you run debugger and see if you even get to that part of your code to throw a message at all?

Comment: In all cases, my code adds a message to the `FacesContext` object. I even check that internally, my added message is stored. The FacesContext does store it in its internal list. For a reason I can't explain, I can't receive my message back(empty xml response). If I use a growl component, I can see the message on the screen (fulle xml response) though...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem recently with PrimeFaces 6.0.19.

It turns out that I must have to call `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed()` before I call the addMessage() method so the message can be properly shown.

i.e.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
//if you set the client ID to be null, you should add globalOnly=true in <p:messages>
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Connection failed.", t.getLocalizedMessage()));
```